# relative layout can't wrap and keep stretching

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

i have this layout
[image]

i have set the grey box width to wrap_content but it won't wrap instead it just stretched like usual. this is die xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_photo" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_image"
    android:background="#cccccc" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Name"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_text_1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Message"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

just like chat list item in common, you know, the box should wrap the content inside it right?
so how can i achieve this?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

this is my right aligned chat item box, xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_photo" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_image"
    android:background="#cccccc" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Name"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Message"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for the left aligned chat box in case for another user, you just have to remove android:layout_gravity and android:gravity! Thanks!

Comment: why your image view outof relative layout???

Comment: there are two relative layout, the image view is in the outer one while those two textviews is inside inner reelative layout

Comment: @user724861 It would be helpful to see this outer layout as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

from

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_1"
        ...
```

as you want to align its parent not the view itself

Comment: wow! thanks! i dont' understand like that detail. and for those who want to make a chat list item, i have updated my question up there, hope can helps!